# Relationship between collation and encoding

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Does SQL Server enforce or control the encoding of `VARCHAR` columns in some way? The documentation I've browsed does not make a clear distinction about collation (sort and compare rules) and encoding (byte representation of a given character).

I have a SQL Server instance where everything is `Modern_Spanish_CI_AS` (including database, tables and columns), which I got the impression that meant `Windows-1252`. Database is populated by an application that uses Windows-1252 as well. Recently, a misconfigured application that uses UTF-8 has been writing data for a while and, to my surprise, SQL Server happily accepts the complete Unicode catalogue and, not only that, other clients I've tried appear to read data back correctly no matter what application the table belongs to.

When I cast to hex:

```
SELECT foo, CAST(foo AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS hex
FROM ...;
```

... I see different encodings depending on what application the table belongs to:

- First app:

  ```
  €Á    0x80C1
  ```
- Second app:

  ```
  €Á    0xAC20C100
  ```

... but raw characters display properly.

How can SQL clients know the source encoding?

---

**Edit:** if both apps write into the same table I find this:

```
€Á      0x80C1
â‚¬Ã    0xE282ACC381
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a guess but seems supported by my testing and assorted documentation browsing. Special binary collations aside, SQL Server only considers two types of string data:

- Legacy (single-byte)
- Unicode (multi-byte)

Legacy data is expected to be encoded in whatever code page the underlying Windows system is configured to use. Unicode is less of a problem since the character repertoire is mostly the same. In either case, it's the driver used by the client the one that takes care of conversions (if any) and usual driver configurations only include a few options that reflect this fact (e.g. raw, ANSI, UTF-8). For this reasons, SQL Server does not have a setting or directive to choose the character set as other DBMS's have and you only need to choose a collation in the usual meaning of the term (sort and compare rules).

As about how to distinguish between the two possible encodings, it all depends on the column type:

- `CHAR`, `VARCHAR`, `TEXT`... imply ANSI
- `NCHAR`, `NVARCHAR`, `NTEXT`... imply Unicode

If you use the incorrect encoding for a given column type you'll just get garbage like `â‚¬Ã`.